# Can a Windows application using only Win32 be certified for the Windows Store?

Tags: c, winapi, com, windows-store-apps

Can a Windows application be certified for the Windows Store if it **ONLY** uses [the allowed Win32 subset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br205757.aspx) and is written in [plain C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/946294/193892)?

<sub>[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909139/can-windows-store-applications-be-built-with-mingw#comment17509787_12909139)</sub>

Comment: Are you talking about a Modern UI (Metro) application or a desktop app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Among other reasons, a Windows Store app must have a user interface, and the Win32 APIs callable from a Windows Store app do not include the functionality required to build a user interface.

You can certainly build a Windows Store app using C, though doing so does not sound like fun.